# How to connect to Droxbox via sftp Python?

Tags: python, sftp

I want to send/download file from Droxbox via Python. I've tried `pysftp` and `paramiko`, but the `connect()` call will hang. Below is my code.

```
import paramiko

# create a client
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# can alos choose .WarningPolicy(), .RejectPolicy()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname="dropbox.com", username="my username", password="my pw")
# The call will hang there
```

sftp code

```
import pysftp as sftp
cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

'''If I don't set up cnopts, I'll get error - No hostkey for host dropbox.com found.
But I got a warning if I set up the above cnopts - 
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of 
public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future 
version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
self.ecdsa_curve.curve_class(), pointinfo
'''
s = sftp.Connection(host="dropbox.com",
                    username="xi@transcriptic.com",                             
                    password="Python@2018",
                    cnopts=cnopts)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think that Dropbox supports FTP or SSH?

Comment: Oh, then sad! Do you know which public website support SFTP?

Comment: It seems they provide a package for python for http access - https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Comment: @Guy Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Dropbox supports SFTP, sadly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Do you know which public website support SFTP, then I can test sftp transfer files. Thank you!